# Отображение ответа

Tags: python, opencv

Попытался сделать код для поиска объекта по шаблону, но не могу понять как сделать чтоб если скрипт нашел объект, то выводил в `print` что он нашел объект, если пишу `print ( res )` и он видит объект то пишет кучу цифр, если объект закрыл чем нить то он пишет нули, но иногда если заменить объект то пишет цифры различные. Как сделать ответ?

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2

template = cv2.imread ("base.png", 0)

base_screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1450, 220, 1500, 240,))
base_screen.save ("base_screen.png")

img_rgb = cv2.imread("base_screen.png")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor (img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
print (res)
```

Comment: Потому что он всегда что-нибудь находит, просто менее похожее. Надо степень похожести найденного проверять. Надо читать доку по cv2. `matchTemplate` сообщает что нашёл, с какой метрикой и по каким координатам. Соответственно надо смотреть метрику первого что он там нашёл, оно самое близкое должно быть. Если метрика устраивает - считаем, что нашлось искомое, а если метрика плохая, то не нашёл.